# Django Models: combine multiple fields entries for one field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am making a site for a competition and I have a model something like this

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
            return "Participant: " +  str(self.uuid)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    participant = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    redditusername = models.CharField("Reddit Username",max_length=21)
    slackusername = models.CharField("Slack Username", max_length=21)
    challengeone = models.CharField("Points for challenge 1", max_length=30,blank=False)
    challengetwo = models.CharField("Points for challenge 2", max_length=30,blank=False)
    challengethree = models.CharField("Points for challenge 3", max_length=30,blank=False)
    challengefour = models.CharField("Points for challenge 4", max_length=30,blank=False)
    challengefive = models.CharField("Points for challenge 5", max_length=30,blank=False)   
    totalpoints = models.CharField("Points for all challenges ", max_length=30,blank=False)
```

This is a terrible design I know. I have to input the points manually. Calculate the points and then add them to the `totalpoints`. The question I have is how can I combine the challengeone, two, three, four, five and get the total points and have a field `totalpoints` where the field points are added to that one automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [override the models' `save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading) method for this.

Something like this:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    #... blah

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.totalpoints = self.challengeone + self.challengetwo #+ ...
        super(Participant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, this works automatically everytime the `save` method is called.

Since you have `blank=False` (which infact is the default, so you do not have to specify it) - this ensures the database does not fail on insert.

Another way you can approach this is by using [django's `presave` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) which has the same net effect, but achieved through a signal

Answer (score 1):

You can use @property decorater in models to calculate the result.
Something like:

```
@property
def totalpoints():
    return <Your Query here>
```

Now, in case you don't want to make a query each time to retrieve the `totalpoints` you can use a Django signal method called `post_save()`
Which you can read about [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save). Whenever there is an updation in points anywhere in the model class you specified, this method will be called and the result can be stored in regular Integer type field `totalpoints`.

Comment: This approach sure works, but just wanted to point out that the post_save would work, provided the field is marked as nullable.